# DynamoDB GeoHash Scoped to individual user ID results

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Is there a way to implement a DynamoDB GeoHash with results scoped to an individual user ID (or arbitrary lookup key)?

This is my use case: A user can create points of interest that have a coordinate. I want to look up all of these points of interest for the user within a certain radius of a coordinate. Obviously implementing the regular GeoHash would be incredibly inefficient because the GeoHash would give me the points of interest from EVERY user. Then I would have to filter for results that match the requester's user ID.

Creating a DynamoDB table per user. Not an option because of how many users I have.

I have considered forgoing the GeoHash entirely. Since the number of points of interest a user will have is relatively low I could just fetch all points of interest for a user in the majority of cases. However, ideally I would implement the more scalable GeoHash solution and never have to revisit my implementation in the future.